# T-SQL - Is it possible to query a table through a series of Linked Servers?

Tags: sql-server

Server A has a Linked Server connection to Server B.  Server B has a Linked Server Connection to Server C.  I would like to query a table on Server C from Server A.  Is there a syntax, or a way to do it with multiple statements?

I tried `[LinkedServerB].[LinkedServerC].[Database].[Table]`, running from Server A. No luck.

Comment: I tried [LinkedServerB].[LinkedServerC].[Database].[Table], running from Server A.  No luck.

Comment: I don't have a set up to try this, but quick search gave this syntax:

select foo.id 
    from databaseserver1.db1.dbo.table1 foo
        inner join databaseserver2.db1.dbo.table1 bar 
            on foo.name = bar.name

Comment: If you can do it through one hop like that maybe it would allow for a second?

Comment: I know you can do A to B.  But I don't know if you can do A *through* B to C. Maybe you can call a stored procedure or something on Server B from Server A that gets what you need from server C?

Comment: You may build a view in Server B query Server C tables, then access the view by Server A. But I think it is dangerous to reference other server's linked server, in terms of both security and change impact analysis.

Comment: Thanks, user1011627..  I might be misunderstanding your suggestion, but I'm trying to select data from a table that I don't have direct access to.  In other words, databaseserver1 has a Linked Server connection to databaserver2.  databaseserver2 has a Linked Server connection to databaseserver3.  databaseserver1 does not have a connection to 3, but I was hoping I could get to the data through the chain of linked servers.  For example, running a query from databaseserver1, I would think it would be something like select * from databaseserver2.databaseserver3.datababasename.table.

Comment: Thanks, Timothy.  The Stored Procedure call to build a temporary table on the "middle" server might be a good solution.

Comment: Thanks, Eric, I like the View answer as well.  It's similar to the SP answer to build a "temp" table, because in both cases, there has to be some sort on intermediate table or view.  Our solution now is to use SSIS with connections to linked servers, but I am looking to see if I can avoid that.

Comment: To follow up, I used the View idea.  I created a View on databaseserver2; "select * from databaseserver3.database.dbo.table".  Then from databaseserver1 I am able to select what I need from that View.  Thanks for your help!